# Transformation of an Unimodular Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Unimodular Matrix is a matrix, which has integer entries and determinant of $\in \{+1,-1\}$. That means the matrix is invertible over the integers $\mathbb{Z}$.

Given a unimodular matrix A for example:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 2  & -2  & -5 &  -4 &  -2 &  -3 \\
    0 &   1  &  0  &  0   & 0   & 0 \\
 -1  &  0  &  3  &  1 &  -1  &  0\\
    0  &  0  &  0 &   1  &  0  &  0\\
    0  &  0  &  0 &   0  &  1  &  0\\
    0  &  0  &  0 &   0  &  0  &  1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I need to convert to it to a matrix like this:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 *  & *  & * &  * &  * &  * \\
    * &   *  &  0  &  0   & 0   & 0 \\
 *  &  0  &  *  &  0 &  0  &  0\\
    *  &  0  &  0 &   *  &  0  &  0\\
    *  &  0  &  0 &   0  &  *  &  0\\
    *  &  0  &  0 &   0  &  0  &  *
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where * denotes possible nonzero entries.

I am only allowed to right-multiply the start matrix with an unimodular matrix $M$, where the first row of the transformation matrix $M$ needs to be $\begin{bmatrix} 1  & 0  & \cdots &  0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$

So i'm only allowed to use A' = A*M, where A' is the new desired Matrix.

How can i find such a transformation matrix, or decide that it is not possible? Any ideas would be helpfull!

Comment: The only other idea I have is: if $A$ is unimodular then so is it's inverse, so let $M = A^{-1}M'$ where $M'$ is unimodular of the form you want and chosen such that $A^{-1}M$ has the desired first row.

Comment: yes but i don't know of the values of M'. Can you expand this a little bit more?

Comment: Start by computing $A^{-1}$

Comment: The inverse is: $$\begin{bmatrix}3& 6& 5& 7& 11& 9 \\
 0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
 1& 2& 2& 2& 4& 3 \\
 0& 0& 0& 1& 0& 0 \\
 0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 0\\
 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: How do we progress from there i know the form of M', but not the values.

Comment: Now use column operations, subtract the first column from the third and then use the $1$ in the third column to zero out the rest of the third row.  This will create a $1$ at the top of the first column, use that to zero out the rest of the first row.